# How to re-structure this for loop so the next iteration doesn't happen until an asynchronous api call completes

Tags: javascript

So below we have schools an array like school[key] = value.

```
for(key in schools) {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = schools[key];
        var org_code = key;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
             //callback function
        })
}
```

I need to use the key/org_code inside the callback function but obviously the for loop iterates faster than the geocode api call completes so the incorrect key is used in the callback function.

I tried to use array.shift to rewrite the above as a function and to use that function in the callback but I wasn't able to do it... for one thing I couldn't access the key with that method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a closure:

```
for(key in schools) {
    (function(key) {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = schools[key];
        var org_code = key;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            //callback function
        })
    })(key)
}
```

Comment: Very nice, clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use an immediately invoked function expression to create a closure, scoping the variables for each iteration:

```
for (key in schools) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = schools[key];
    var org_code = key;
    (function(address, org_code) {
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
        }, function (results, status) {
            //callback function
        })
    })(address, org_code);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion using a closure :

```
for(key in schools) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = schools[key];
    var org_code = key;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(org_code, address) {
        return function (results, status) {
            // use address and org_code here
        };
    }(org_code, address))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use recursive function. To get key - reformat schools array.

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function geocodeNext(sch) {
  var item = sch.shift();
  var address = item['address'];
  var key = item['key'];
  geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    //do something with key
    geocodeNext(sch);
  })
}

var schools1 = [];
for var (key in schools) {
  schools1.push({'address': schools[key], 'key': key});
}

geocodeNext(schools1);
```